# Scheme Language - Background running application - Error Analysis after crash

Tags: scheme

Do I have any chance to get a stack backtrace or similar
of a running scheme background process. Or to dump an Image
on any exception or error of the running system which I can
examine later ?

**EDITED**
to be more precise
On Unix I have been running a web application (started in background from shell via &). Now I want to get some debuggable stuff in case of any error. for example stack backtrace, Image Dump (core dump), or such.

this probably is easy to get in Common Lisp, Java or Smalltalk, but I don't have any clue how to achieve this with Scheme.

thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by scheme background process? There are no scheme reports that has fork or thread support so to run portable scheme in background the shell needs to do this for you.

There are no mention on how to return a value either, but printing to stderr can be done in the standard using the port given by `(current-error-port)‌`

For everything else you can try to find SRFIs to make it semi portable and hope your implementation has implemented it or else you are locking yourself in by using non portable code.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question here.

I have found a portable Debugger for Scheme Language:

seems a bit dated
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/lang/scheme/code/debug/psd/

seems to be more recent:
https://bitbucket.org/certainty/psd

PSD is instrumenting the original source program, so this should be an attractive DIY solution.